# Mostrar la ventana de bienvenida en Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Estoy aprendiendo programación. He descargado VS Code; quité la opción de que aparezca la ventana de welcome o bienvenido. Ahora mismo no sé cómo se puede volver a habilitar esa opción.

Ahora me aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo habilitar de nuevo esa opción?

Comment: [¿Esto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504877/welcome-page-in-visual-studio-code-how-to-get-it#comment126889383_43063391)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la opción :D

Adjunto una captura de pantalla para habilitar la opción.

[image: opcion de inicio vscode]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Describe el contenido de la captura de pantalla. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta, y lee [answer].